# Convert Date Field to UTC in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, utc

I am trying to convert a date field 'createdate' to UTC time but the ask is to be -04:00. I have tried a bunch of things and have had no success. I am working on Oracle. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  A `date` doesn't have a time zone.  If you want to convert it from one time zone to another, we'd need to know what time zone to infer the `date` is from and what time zone you want to convert to.  You seem to say that you want to convert to UTC but you also say you want to convert to "-04:00".  And you don't tell us what time zone to assume the date is currently in.  If you want to convert from -4:00 to UTC, just add 4 hours.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
cast(createdate as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC'
```

This converts the `createdate` to a timestamp with your *current* time zone (the one that is defined by your client through `SESSIONTIMEZONE`). It then converts that to UTC.

Comment: This is not fully correct, when you cast from `TIMESTAMP` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then Oracle takes your current local time zone, i.e. `SESSIONTIMEZONE`, not the time zone of database server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks, corrected (I don't think I have ever worked in a system where the clients and the DB server where in different time zones...)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible if you have a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` value, because those data types do not have any time zone information and thus it is not possible to convert to any other time zone - unless you treat the value as "local time zone".

There are several solutions:

- `createdate at time zone 'UTC'`
- `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(createdate)`
- `FROM_TZ(createdate, 'UTC')`

The result types are different, e.g. `FROM_TZ` returns as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values, whereas `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` returns a `TIMESTAMP` value.